# How to declare generic function for converting to an array in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I have a general function for wrapping anything to an array:

```js
const ensureArray = <T,>(value?: T | T[]): T[] => {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) return value
  if (value === undefined) return []
  return [value]
}

const undef = undefined
ensureArray(undef) // result type undefined[]

const str = 'string'
ensureArray(str)  // result type string[]

const strArray = ['string']
ensureArray(strArray)  // result type string[]

interface Interface {
  [key: string]: string | string[] | number | number[]
}
const p:Interface ={a:'x'}
ensureArray(p.a)  
// types as const ensureArray: <string | number>(value?: string | number | (string | number)[] | undefined) => (string | number)[]
```

Is there a way to make the TypeScript deduce the function type as

```js
(value: string | number | string[] | number[] | undefined) => string[] | number[]
```

?

Fiddle with the example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAppArgJzgQWcghgTxgXhgB4AVAGgD4AKANywBtE4B+ALhhJgB8OBtAXQCU7EgIIUYAbwBQMGAEsAZjCoZsOAHTyIa3LQZNBgmKigowMOoziyFy-dYL5CiMABM4i+WDhvjp8xgBWwDkC14rJn5pAF9paVBIWFcPZRd3T29faQQIFHRMPRTPQXjE6BhoZAIYAHIq7wBzWpykVF0cKirShPAKqo6a3nqoZCba6Nz8jq7Rjp7vKDhkRSxgOBgASTAllbWNmTleAGs4HHYGsEb+C9Gm7kq7q7EeMEQAWwAjZYe3r+XgnFyrAAA6sba7VbrAiSLCsWoAD1qcSm7UKnRBGiwpSAA

Answer (score 2):

I would add an overload to the function where the return type is a conditional type.

```
function ensureArray<T,>(value?: T | T[]): T extends any[] ? T : T[]
function ensureArray<T,>(value?: T | T[]): T[] {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) return value
  if (value === undefined) return []
  return [value]
}
```

We can check if `T` is an array type. If it is, just return it. If not, return `T[]`. The overload will stop TypeScript from complaining about the `return` statements in the actual implementation.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgKYQM5gE6oILbYCGAngDwAqANAHwAUAbkQDZioD8AXMhcgD48A2gF0AlN16oAHjHQATDMiIQSI5Ox7IJI0JFiIU6LLgLFy1ek1YcJ-IWO3DkAb2DJkcEMjqnSAOjgMXxJGFjZRUWRcGBwUKzY3Dy9Q62QAXgzkSDlUEDgIVDlI6NjkHXcS7BRBeNRhYABfYGAoJAwYLIgcrzTO7vzC4CMcfEJSOmzc0WbWzA727HTkAHIF-IBzZaHMEeC6BemWtvmYbGClwVXTjeX64ZMxkIXgw-zZbBAiKFRkAEkId6fb4uRKCADWqBI3DWEHWwmh11hdhh6zUAggYAAtgAjVCLdFY3HYHRNWbtZAAB04-0BXx%20aWcRE4yykyya91GZjoFL8RGmQA)

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Maybe small modification:

    function ensureArray<T,>(value?: T): T extends any[] ? T : T[]
    function ensureArray<T,>(value?: T | T[]): T[] {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) return value
      if (value === undefined) return []
      return [value]
    }